# Error: fs could not be found within the project while using dotenv in expo project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo, dotenv

I am working on an expo app. I want to use environment variables so I installed dotenv package.
When I add require('dotenv').config() in my App.js I am getting this error.

```
undefined Unable to resolve module fs from C:\Users\RohitMaurya\Music\kaam_karo\frontend\GoalrApp\node_modules\dotenv\lib\main.js: fs could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  22 | */
  23 |
> 24 | const fs = require('fs')
     |                     ^
  25 | const path = require('path')
  26 | const os = require('os')
  27 |
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\HMRClient.js:320:31 in showCompileError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\HMRClient.js:227:26 in client.on$argument_1
at node_modules\eventemitter3\index.js:181:21 in emit
at node_modules\metro\src\lib\bundle-modules\HMRClient.js:142:10 in _ws.onmessage
at node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\WebSocket\WebSocket.js:231:8 in _eventEmitter.addListener$argument_1        
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue       
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Unable to resolve module fs from C:\Users\RohitMaurya\Music\kaam_karo\frontend\GoalrApp\node_modules\dotenv\lib\main.js: fs could not be found within the project.
```

Comment: same error for me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a babel plugin like [`react-native-dotenv`](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv) (shameless plug)

```
npm i -D react-native-dotenv
```